# Fast algorithmn for deciding whether a polynomial system of inequalities has a solution

Tags: algorithm, polynomial-math, inequality

I am looking for a fast algorithmn that decides whether a given system of k polynomial inequalities in n variables has a solution ( I do not need the solution )

For k > n.

I have read about Cylindrical Algebraic Decomposition but have not been able to find anything better than that so far.

EDIT:

It is about polynomials with real coefficients over the real numbers.

Comment: What do you consider to be a solution? For instance X^2 + 2X + 1 < 0 has no real solution, but has complex solution. Can you specify your question?

Comment: @LajosArpad: since we're talking about inequalities, it think it's safe to assume the variables are real, as there's no clear ordering for complex numbers. (eg: what if X=i)

Comment: In polynomial inequalities we are comparing the values of the polynom, not the values of the parameter (x) to n. In the complex plane the solution for such an inequality would be the set of areas where the points (x, y being the coordinates) used as parameter in the polynomial function fulfills the inequality.

Comment: huh?  I'm talking about the polynom. i^2 + 2i + 1 < 0, which is the same as 2i < 0. is that inequality true or false? :)

Comment: @KarolyHorvath, that's not a polynomial inequality, it is just an inequality. If you talk about a polynom, like X^2 + 2X + 1 < 0, with a value of i, then the result is not comparable with 0, you are right about that, however, in this case i would be outside the domain where the polynomial inequality is applicable. We must take into consideration the set of values where the result of the function is comparable with 0.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath also, if you have a comparator function which has a boolean result for any two complex numbers, then you can use that for your comparison and in that case 2i can be compared to 0. It all depends on the specification of the problem. So your concern is valid, however it must be answered by the op, who, apparently answered both of our questions in his edit.

Comment: note: I talked about the polynom right from the beginning. and then "I'm talking about the polynom." - "If you talk about a polynom" *grin*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any other solution is not known. You have to enumerate the components in some kind of CAD by finding at least one point per component and then check those points for satisfying the inequalities.

You can read about the modern approaches in Basu, Pollack, Roy: ["Algorithms in real algebraic geometry"](http://perso.univ-rennes1.fr/marie-francoise.roy/bpr-ed2-posted2.html)

Comment: Thats too bad. CAD has a too high complexity for the number of variables I am using. My basic problem is solving the realizability of oriented matroids problem which I read reduces down to this polynomial problem. However since I'm looking at 4500 polynomials with 50 or more variables (roughly) this seems infeasible to do in a couple of seconds.

Comment: @LutzL Another solution is to use Positivstellensatz certificates. I explained this in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Maple's package regular chains has a command IsEmpty?

> The command IsEmpty(sys, R) checks whether the zero set of the set of constraints sys  is empty or not. The constraints in sys can be any polynomial equations, inequations or inequalities given by polynomials of R. The zero set of sys is regarded as the set of the real solutions of the polynomial system defined by sys. This assumes that R has characteristic zero.

I'm not sure what is the algorithm used but see:

Xia, Bican, and Lu Yang. "An algorithm for isolating the real solutions of semi-algebraic systems." Journal of Symbolic Computation 34, no. 5 (2002): 461-477.

Answer (score 1):

Deciding if a system of polynomial inequalities is feasible is a very hard mathematical problem and a lot of research in real algebraic geometry has to do with it.

Apart from cylindrical algebraic decomposition there are theorems of the alternative also for these sets. The most notable result is [Stengle's Positivstellensatz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stengle's_Positivstellensatz) which roughly says that if it is infeasible, then you can prove that it is infeasible by combining the positivity requirements from the constraints in a positive way so that the result is -1. This contradiction proves infeasibility.

Finding these certificates can be very bad algorithmically, but you can look at so called moment relaxations of your set.  These are slighly larger sets whose feasibility can be decided with semi-definite programming.  Algorithms for this are well-developed.

In total, there is a hierarchy of larger and larger convex optimization problems in which you eventually find a solution to the question of infeasibility. Of course in practice all this can be spoiled by numerical problems, etc. An implementation of this is the Matlab package [yalmip](http://users.isy.liu.se/johanl/yalmip/)

Answer (score -1):

Assuming that the parameter is real you can find the roots of the polynom (assuming that you include n into the polynom) and  the solution would be the set of intervals where X is greater than 0.

You can also use the results of the derivatives to determine the trend of the function.